# How can i add a nft to an existing collection

Tags: metaplex

I want to create a collection where i can add nfts manually afterwards. I would like to use the Metaplex sdk, but other libraries are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two steps that you have to take:

1. Create the collection NFT parent ([JS SDK Example](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create))

```
const { nft } = await metaplex.nfts().create({
   uri: "https://arweave.net/123",
   name: "My NFT",
   sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500, // Represents 5.00%.
});
```

2. Optional: Migrate to a sized collection ([JS SDK API reference](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/classes/js.NftClient.html#migrateToSizedCollection))

```
metaplex
  .nfts()
  .migrateToSizedCollection({ mintAddress, size: toBigNumber(10000) });
```

4. Use "set and verify" instruction to assign the NFT to the collection ([JS SDK API reference](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/classes/js.NftClient.html#verifyCollection)):

```
metaplex.nfts().verifyCollection({mintAddress, collectionMintAddress,  isSizedCollection: false})
```